Android Intent extras stripped from the intent when sent through google messages
I’m fairly new to Android, been looking at sharing data between apps using the Android intent resolver.
What I want to do is share an image from my App to the google messages app to be sent as a message to another user on their device. The other user will tap on that image in the received message, and this will bring up my App on their device and the image will be handled in my App on their device.
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Word List: Cat Breeds");
Uri path = Uri.parse("content://com.example.myapp.assets/Share/Share_Word_List_Image.png");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.messaging");
sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);


Bundle extras = new Bundle();
String CatBreeds = "Cat Breeds,YES,NO,Abyssinian,Aegean,American Bobtail,American Curl";
extras.putString("com.example.myapp.wordlist", CatBreeds);
sendIntent.putExtras(extras);

startActivity(sendIntent);

This works well. As you can see, I put a bundle into the intent with some extra information.
This intent gets passed to messages, and everything looks good, the intent is intact, all information gets passed to the message’s activity.
The image gets attached to the message; the message text is passed into the text box.
All you have to do is it the send button to send it on its way.
Which I do.
Message arrives at other device, Image and text all there.
I tap on the image and it brings up the intent resolver displaying the apps I can send this image to including my App since it has the proper intent filter.
I select my App and it starts up and begins the routine for handling this incoming content (image).
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

The intent I get is not the same intent that was sent.
All the information is gone including the Bundle I put into the intent.
So, can you not send an intent with extras through messaging?
Is this a security issue that strips the extras when attached to a message?
I scrubbed permissions to see if it was a permission issue.
Didn’t see anything.
My Intent and Bundle after being passed to the messages App:
Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=image/png flg=0x30000000 pkg=com.google.android.apps.messaging (has extras) }
Bundle[{com.example.myapp.wordlist=Cat Breeds,YES,NO,Abyssinian,Aegean,American Bobtail,American Curl,American Wirehair,York Chocolate}]
The Intent and Bundle received at the other device:
Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=image/png flg=0x1b080001 cmp=com.example.myapp/.MainActivity clip={image/png {...}} (has extras) }
Bundle[{android.intent.extra.STREAM=content://com.google.android.apps.messaging.shared.datamodel.ProxyProvider/-5210306894503040597.png}]
Any insights would be helpful.
Thanks
Andy
I expected the Intent to remain complete once sent through the Android messaging app.
